Loadrunner Truclient - Upload CSV Issue
I have a use case where I need to upload a CSV file via LR truclient protocol.
When I am trying to upload normal IE browser, file is getting uploaded properly. But in truclient browser it's throwing "File Upload Error".
I verified the request which is sending in both cases.
With Normal Browser - Content-type: text/csv and csv content is not going via request body to server
With Truclient Browser - Content:type: application/vnd.ms-excel and csv content is going via request body to server.
Would be helpful if there is any observation on this or how to fix the request header type or change the way to send request using Truclient protocol

Just script this business process in HTTP virtual user and you will have control of virtually every attribute.

Thanks James for your comment! I believe you mean HTTP protocol instead of truclient. In that case how will i achieve UI performance testing like page rendering time etc. ?

Measure rendering time during functional testing with single users.   Pull the navtiming and log metrics into a tool like Splunk, Datadog, dynatrace, etc.... Rendering a client function.  You will never be able control the resources on the client.  Multi user testing is about server performance
